# How to use preprocess function for custom templates defined in hook_theme?

Tags: theming

I have a custom module that i've created and I have set the theme template like this:

```
/**
 * Implemtnation of hook_theme()
 */
function custom_slider_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
    return array(
        'custom_slider' => array(
            'variables' => array('nodes' => NULL),
            'template' => 'custom_slider',
        ),
    );
}
```

This is all working fine.

What I can't find is how to load a css file for that template so when `custom_slider.tpl.php` is loaded the relevent css file is loaded. I don't need that css loaded on every page. I would rather call `drupal_add_css()` only when it's needed.

I used below approach, but it's not working.

```
function ModuleName_preprocess_TemplateName(&$vars) {
      drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'custom_slider') . '/file.css');
    }
```

Also I added

```
'preprocess functions' =>array('ModuleName_preprocess_TemplateName'),
```

in hook_theme, where I defined my templates, kindly suggest the right way to do it.

Any help with this is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Drupal will automatically call `hook_preprocess_[template]` for each template defined in `hook_theme`.

e.g:

```
MODULE_preprocess_custom_slider(&$variables){}
```

Should be called by default. If not, then clear your cache to be sure the preprocess function is registered.

Fun fact is preprocess functions are called for theme functions as well, e.g `theme_item_list` calls `hook_preprocess_item_list` prior to rendering.

Comment: I have 4 templates and 4 css files.. css1 belongs to template1, css2 belongfs to template2 and so on..I am using preprocess function so that css1 should only effect to template1 and so on.. `MODULE_preprocess_template1(&$variables){drupal_add_css('css1')}`and `MODULE_preprocess_template2(&$variables){drupal_add_css('css2')}` Is this the right way to apply css on particular template file, so when template1 is invoked, only css1 classes apply on it, not css2 classes. P.S. css1 and css2 contains same classes name.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ModuleName_preprocess_TemplateName(&$vars) {
      drupal_add_css(drupal_get_path('module', 'custom_slider') . '/file.css');
    }
```

This function works perfectly, just ensure that the css file is in the same folder as the .tpl.php and .module files